# Same object access in different activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a Java class say J.java

```
//j.java
class J
{


}
```

and I have 2 activity say A1,A2.
In A1 I created a object of class J.

```
A1
{
  J obj = new J();
}
```

> Question- I want to access the same object(obj) in A2.

```
A2
{
   obj // how can I access this object here? this is created in A1.
}
```

Comment: Couple of options. 1. Make the class J as a static class or you can use singleton pattern. 2. Wrap it in an intent or bundle and then send it to other activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for that object. And send that object from A1 to A2 into intent extra.***

[Parcel data to pass between Activities using Parcelable classes](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/) is a very good example to implement  [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Comment: did you get your answer? Is there any confusion? :)

Answer (score 1):

one way to have a single instance of `J` across the activities is to have a singleton for the `J` object.

one way of doing this is having an instance in the application level (have a `J` instance in a class that extends `Application`.

the other way is doing this:

```
class J {
    private static J instance = null;

    private J() {
    }

    public static J get() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Base or Parent activity. Initialize your object in base activity and extend your all classes from base or application activity.